# ANTLR4 JavaScript parser: how to catch an error in parsing

Tags: javascript, parsing, antlr4

I have a grammar in ANTLR4 around which I am writing an application. A snippet of the pertinent grammar is shown below:

```
grammar SomeGrammar;
// ... a bunch of other parse rules
operand
   : id | literal ;
id
   : ID ;
literal
   : LITERAL ;
// A bunch of other lexer rules
LITERAL       : NUMBER | BOOLEAN | STRING;
NUMBER        : INTEGER | FLOAT ;
INTEGER       : [0-9]+ ;
FLOAT         : INTEGER '.' INTEGER | '.' INTEGER ;
BOOLEAN       : 'TRUE' | 'FALSE' ;
ID            : [A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9_]* ;
STRING        : '"' .*? '"' ;
```

I generate the `antlr4` JavaScript Lexer and Parser like so:

```
$ antlr4 -o . -Dlanguage=JavaScript -listener -visitor
```

and then I overload the `exitLiteral ()` prototype to check if an operand is a literal. The issue is that if I pass

```
a
```

it (force) parses it to a literal, and throws an error (e.g. below shown with `grun`):

```
$ grun YARL literal -gui -tree
a
line 1:0 mismatched input 'a' expecting LITERAL
(literal a)
```

The same error when I use the JavaScript Parser which I overloaded like so:

```
SomeGrammarLiteralPrinter.prototype.exitLiteral = function (ctx) {
    debug ("Literal is " + ctx.getText ()); // Literal is a
    };
```

I would like to catch the error so that I can decide that it is an `ID`, and not a `LITERAL`. How do I do that?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why not just use `operand`?

Comment: @sepp2k: I specifically *need* to know if it is a literal or operand, but I get your point. I think I could check with the same lexing rules in my application and use the `operand` like you said, but I was wondering if there is an antlr4 parser way.

Comment: I don't have much experience with ANTLR4, but you'll know that based on which listener/visitor method will be called, no?

Comment: @sepp2k, I think you are right about that too. I need to go back to the drawing board to understand how I am using the listeners. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better solution is to adjust the grammar so that it accurately describes the intended syntax to begin with:

```
startRule : ruleA ruleB EOF ;
ruleA     : something operand anotherthing ;
ruleB     : id assign literal  ;

operand   : ID | LITERAL ;
id        : ID ;
literal   : LITERAL ;
```

The parser performs a top-down graph evaluation of the parser rules, starting with the `startRule`.  That is, the parser will evaluate the listed `startRule` elements in order, sequentially descending through the named sub-rules (and just those sub-rules).  Consequently, `ruleA` will not encounter/consider the `id` and `literal` rules.

In this limited example then, there is no conflict in the seemingly overlapping definition of the `operand`, `id`, and `literal` rules.

**Update**

The `OperandContext` class will contain `ID()` and `LITERAL()` methods returning `TerminalNode`.  The one that does not return null represents the symbol that was actually matched in that specific context. Look at the generated code.

Comment: Thanks for saving my hide again, GRosenberg. Like I mentioned in the comment on the OP to sepp2k, I think I need to go back to the drawing board wrt how I use the listeners and parser. It would help my cause tremendously if the main rule's parse tree also gave me the specific type of token it matched as I walked it, but I cannot seem to get that to work.

Comment: Appreciate your update on this, GRosenberg. Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you again!